# Installing a smart switch: weird wiring at my current one

Tags: switch

I have recently bought a house and doing some renovations. I am planning to change my switches to smart switches. To check if possible (neutral wire etc), I bought one and tried to wire it to one of my current switches. However, I found a weird situation behind the wall.

First of all, the cables are all the same color! Secondly, I have the line wire into the top slot of the switch, and then 2 wires into the other slot. The switch is a 2 gang one and both are wired in the same way, with the line wire connected with a bridge. I thought about possibly a two-way switch but it is the only switch in the room, and each gang controls a set of lights.

So I got out my multimeter and here’s what I have:

If I connect to ground and the wire:

- W1: 220V (line)
- W2: 0V
- W3: 0V

If I connect the line and the wire:

- W1+W2: 0V (W2 is load?)
- W1+W3: 220V (W3 is neutral?)

The weirdness continues cause I tried to connect the smart switch (a Sonoff T2 with Tasmota), and if I connect according to the needs (the 2 neutrals in the neutral slot, line, and then the 2 loads), the switch turns on but the lights don’t work. If I connect 1 neutral into neutral, line, and 1 load and neutral together, the light work (only one, the one with the load and neutral connected together).

I’m lost!

(PS: consider I’m living in the UAE, wiring should be according to UK standards)

[image: current switch setup]

[image: connection to new smart switch, switch works but lights don’t]

Comment: "Dumb" switches don't have or need neutrals, so none of those wires are neutral. And you've WAY too much exposed copper between the wire insulation and the switches screw-terminals.

Comment: Hello brhans, thanks for your reply! I was starting to think the same, but then I don't really understand why I have two switch-hot cables going out the switch. Any idea what this could be? Any yes, I know about the copper, as I wasn't sure whether I would keep the switch I didn't modify the cables (the copper fits all in when the old switch is mounted)

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it looks like you had Load1A & Load1B, and Load2A & Load2B rather than Load1, Load2 and some neutrals. How many separate light fixtures did this pair of switches control? Do you maybe have 2 groups of lights?